# javascript capture one input

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to capture the change of this select:

```
 @if (!Model.Id.Equals(null))
            {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modificar.IdClase, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase", Model.Modificar.IdClase), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
            }
            else
            {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListaClases, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px" })
            }
```

Using a variable to take de active

```
var clases = $('#Id').val() != "" ? $('#Modificar_IdClase') : $('#ListaClases');
```

I saw in a `console.log(clases)` the Modificar_IdClase is captured like a input and not like a select. Why it's happening and how can i fix it?

`console.log(clases)`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edit 1**

The html code write in the Chrome DevTools is:

Modificar_IdClase:

```
<select class="input form-control input-lg" id="Modificar_IdClase" name="Modificar.IdClase" required="required" style="height: 40px; font-size:16px">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Articulo principal</option>
<option value="2">Articulo auxiliar</option>
</select>
```

Lista clases:

```
<select class="input form-control input-lg" id="ListaClases" name="ListaClases" required="required" style="height: 40px; font-size:16px">
<option value="1">Articulo principal</option>
<option value="2">Articulo auxiliar</option>
</select>
```

the problem is in the `DropDownListFor` one is getting data and gets `input` and not `select`

Comment: What is the actual HTML that your JavaScript is interacting with?  Do you have any other elements with that same ID anywhere on the page?

Comment: @David there is two options one to modify and other to create a new, only can take one in time, it's a partial view

Comment: The goal of debugging is not to vaguely describe what you want your program to accomplish, but rather to examine the technical runtime details of exactly what the logic is doing.  In this case, since your JavaScript is interacting with HTML and producing an unexpected result, what you'll want to do is examine the HTML and see if it's what you expect it to be.  Your browser provides debugging tools to help with this.  Press F12 in your browser.  Take a look at the DOM explorer, test JavaScript commands in the Console, etc.  To repeat... What is the actual HTML of these elements?

Comment: @David im using asp.net is a cshtml page and the code of the select is the `DropDownListFor` i can do a edit with the devtool of the code transformated, but both are selects

Comment: JavaScript has no knowledge of or visibility to your server-side code.  At this point you're just making assumptions and insisting that your code *should* work.  But since your code *doesn't* work the way you expect it to, now would be a good time to stop making assumptions and start validating and debugging.  A variety of things could be wrong, and may not even be related to the code shown in the question.  But until you start actually debugging, there isn't much anybody can do.

Comment: @David i edited the question with the code create with asp.net, you can see is well writed but when i try to get the select, get a input, i debug the code to find that error

Comment: The code you're showing works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yumjvgkr/

Comment: @David the problem is when i call to the var `clases` you can see the problem 
in the image, take `Modificar_IdClase` like an input, but is a select

Comment: Click on the link I shared and examine the code.  It's the exact code you're showing.  It demonstrably works.  At this point my best guess is that you have another element somewhere else on the page with the same ID.  But that's just a guess, since the code you're showing doesn't demonstrate the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
var clases = $('#Id').val() != "" ? $('#Modificar_IdClase').val() : $('#ListaClases').val();
```

Because `$('#Modificar_IdClase')` return DOM object, if you want to get class for tag you can use `$('#Modificar_IdClase').attr('class')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($('#Modificar_IdClase').val());
console.log($('#Modificar_IdClase').attr('class'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='Modificar_IdClase' class='input form-control input-lg'>
  <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```